# Like button doesn't post to facebook

Tags: html, facebook, post, facebook-like, back

I know there are a lot of posts on this subjects, i've read all of them, but didn;t resolve my problem.

I don't know what happened, it worked fine till a week or two ago. Now, when i click on the like button on my article, i cannot see that on facebook. More, if i write a comment on the like button, still doesn't work.

The code is:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://steagu.ro/index.php?id=<?php echo $myid; ?>&amp;cat=1" data-send="false" data-width="200" data-show-faces="false"></div>
```

I've tried it also with xfbml code, but same result.

Of course, i have the other part needed for facebook, right after body section:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=386320764714835";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

You can test the like button [here](http://steagu.ro/index.php?id=2816&cat=1). The strange part is that I didn't make any changes to the code. The button is counting the likes, but with no effect on facebook page. Since it's happening only to me, must be an error in my website, which I wasn't able to find it

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help but i was using a similar bit of code to yours and it also stopped working so i was googling and found the following which seems to work much better:

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http://www.youwebsitename.co.uk"
                    scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border: none; width: 300px; height: 20px;"></iframe>
```

See the following link 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/

as it mentions in the article the iframe is more widely used and easier to implement.

Hope thats helps

Comment: Thank you for your post. I've tested also the iframe version before, worked for a post and i thought that resolved my problem. But then, it returned to the old habits...

Comment: I've tried again all the solutions provided by facebook, but still no success... Can be a setting from hosting?